# Open CV won't compile

Tags: opencv, compilation, g++, computer-vision

I'm trying to compile some opencv code, but it is failing.  I'm pretty sure I have the libraries included but it still has undefined references to the functions.

I'm running this command:

> gcc -lhighgui -lcvaux -lcxcore -I /usr/local/include/opencv/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -o hello_world hello_world.c

and get this result

> foo.cpp:(.text._ZN3Foo3barEv[Foo::bar()]+0x1f): undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
>
> foo.cpp:(.text._ZN3Foo3barEv[Foo::bar()]+0x2d): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'

with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"


class Foo{
    public:
        void bar(){
          IplImage* img = 0;

      img=cvLoadImage("C:/.../Pictures/image.jpg");  


      cvWaitKey(0);


      system("PAUSE");
    }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ foo->bar(); }
}
```

Comment: I fixed this somehow, I think it was not including libraries correctly or something, I don't quite remember what.

Comment: Your command is missing something like "-lopencv" or something (minus-small-L).